# In Array Insert Nodes inside Node Programmatically

Tags: javascript, c#, arrays

In fruits array I have two Object Fruits and vegetables. In Fruit object I have two nodes apple and mango. Under Apple node I have another two nodes Red apple and green apple.

Like this programatically I have to add another new node under vegetable.

```
$(function() {

        var alternateData = [
          {

        text: 'Fruits',

        nodes: [
          {
            text: 'apple',

            nodes: [
              {
                text: 'Red apple'
              },
              {
                text: 'green apple'
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            text: 'mango'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        text: 'vegetables'

      },
];
```

Comment: What does `C#` have to do with this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var alternateData = [{text: 'Fruits',
    nodes:[{text: 'apple',
          nodes: [{text: 'Red apple'},
                  {text: 'green apple'}]},
          {text: 'mango'}]},{text:'vegetables',nodes:[]}];

var newNode = {text:"veg1",nodes:[]};
alternateData[1].nodes.push(newNode);
```

As long as you define an empty node within the original array, you can push or pop any number of nodes into your "vegetables" element.

Comment: Ok thanks for the reply. can we insert empty nodes programatically into "vegetables" element.. Because initially my array will be empty. if yes please tell me how ??

Comment: you can always define an empty array. look at my edit

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!alternateData[1].nodes) {
   alternateData[1].nodes = [];
}

alternateData[1].nodes.push(newNode);
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined(…) am getting this error .If i use that .Thanks

Comment: updated. looks like your alternateData[1] node does not have a 'nodes' property to store child nodes of it.